# flickrAPI upload photos

Tags: python-3.x, flickr

I'm trying to use python Flickr API to upload photos to my Flickr account. I already got the API key and secret and user them to get information about my albums and photos, but I got some sort of errors trying to upload new photos. Here is my code:

```
import flickrapi
api_key = u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
api_secret = u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)
filename = 'd:/downloads/_D4_6263-Enhanced.png'
title = 'Fach Halcones'
description = 'Posting image using API'
tags = 'fidae'+','+'aviation'+','+'extra'+','+'air shows'
flickr.upload(filename, title, description, tags)
```

When I run the script, I got the following error:

```
File "uploadPhotos.py", line 15, in module
flickr.upload(filename, title, description, tags)
TypeError: upload() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

looking at the Flickr API documentation, it seems to accept up to five arguments (filename,
fileobj, title, description, tags), and I'm passing only four, since fileobj is optional.

I have googled for some examples, but I was unable to find something that does the trick. So, any help would be awesome.

Regards,

Marcio

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, and I'm sharing it here. There were two issues with my code.

First: We must use kwargs; Second: tags must be separated by space, not commas

Here the final version:

```
import flickrapi

api_key = u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
api_secret = u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)

params = {}
params['filename'] = 'd:/downloads/_D4_6263-Enhanced.png'
params['title'] = 'Fach Halcones'
params['description'] = 'Posting image using API'
params['tags'] = '''fidae aviation extra "air shows" '''
flickr.upload(**params)
```

That's it...

Comment: hi, i use this code ,return 
Error: 99: Insufficient permissions. Method requires write privileges; read granted.
how to solve?

Comment: I get a message: "ValueError: Timeout value connect was posting, but it must be an int, float or None." what could it mean?